# Position of Shankha, Chakra, Gadha and Padma in Vishnu's hand

Tags: vishnu, idols

Śrī Viṣṇu to Agnibindu explains different [forms of Mūrtis](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423800.html)

> 215. O Agnibindu of great intellect! Listen, I am enumerating to you (the different forms), O sage. Beginning with the first right-hand (upper) one understand these things in the Sṛṣṭi order (clock-wise).
> 216. Understand the Mūrti of Keśava through Śaṅkha (upper right hand), Cakra (upper left hand), Gadā (lower left hand) and Padma (lower right hand). On being worshipped, this Mūrti shall undoubtedly fulfil the wish (of the worshipper).
> 217. (The Mūrti) Madhuhā should be understood through Śaṅkha (upper right hand), Padma (upper left hand), Gadā (lower left hand) and Cakra (lower right hand). By serving this Mūrti, enemies become destroyed.
> 218. (The Mūrti) Saṅkarṣaṇa should be worshipped with the following as weapons: Śaṅkha (upper right hand), Padma (upper left hand), Cakra (lower left hand) and Gadā (lower right hand). If this Mūrti is worshipped, the creature is never reborn.
> 219. Dāmodara is worshipped with Śaṅkha, Kaumodakī (Gadā), Cakra and Padma (in the order mentioned above). He bestows wealth, sons, cattle-wealth and grains.
> 220. Vāmana is equipped with Śaṅkha, Cakra, Padma and Gadā. When installed in the house, he makes people prosperous.
> 221. Pāñcajanya (i.e. Śaṅkha), Gadā, Padma and Sudarśana (i.e. Cakra) of variegated forms (indicate) Pradyumna who is worshipped by men. He bestows much wealth.
> 222. The six Mūrtis beginning with Viṣṇu are mentioned beginning with upper left hand in the clock-wise order. Merely by remembering it heaps of sins become dissolved.
> 223. For prosperity, Viṣṇu (equipped) with Śaṅkha, Cakra, Gadā and Padma should be worshipped by men. Mādhava with Śaṅkha, Padma, Gadā and Cakra is the bestower of greatest prosperity.
> 224. For perfect achievement Aniruddha should be medidated upon as having Śaṅkha, Padma, Cakra and Gadā lifted up. Puruṣottama (should be meditated upon) as equipped with Śaṅkha, Gadā, Cakra and Padma.
> 225. With Śaṅkha, Cakra, Padma and Gadā, O sage, Adhokṣaja is the remover of further rebirth. Janārdana with Śaṅkha, Kaumodakī (Gadā), Padma and Cakra should be meditated upon.
> 226. The six Mūrtis beginning with Govinda (have the weapons) clock-wise beginning with left lower hand. Govinda always wields Śaṅkha (lower left hand), Cakra (lower right hand), Gadā (upper right hand) and Padma (upper left hand).
> 227. Trivikrama should be worshipped for good fortune with Śaṅkha (lower left hand), Padma (lower right hand), Gadā (right upper hand) and Cakra (left upper hand). Śrīdhara wielding Śaṅkha, Padma, Cakra and Gadā is for prosperity.
> 228. Hṛṣīkeśa is esteemed with Śaṅkha, Gadā, Cakra and Padma. Nṛsiṃha is comprehended through Śaṅkha, Cakra, Padma and Gadā.
> 229. Acyuta is a permanent holder of Śaṅkha along with Gadā, Padma and Cakra. **The six Mūrtis beginning with Vāsudeva should be comprehended beginning with right lower hand.**
>      **230. Vāsudeva always holds Śaṅkha (right lower hand), Cakra (right upper hand), Gadā (upper left hand) and Padma (lower left hand).**
>      **231. O sage, Padmanābha should be known as having Śaṅkha, Padma, Cakra and Gadā. Upendra has always Śaṅkha along with Gadā, Cakra and Padma as his weapons.**
>      **232. Equipped with Śaṅkha, Cakra, Padma and Gadā Hari removes the sins of men. Kṛṣṇa is said to be with Śaṅkha, Gadā, Padma and Cakra.**
>      **233. O great sage, these different Mùrtis of mine have been enumerated, knowing which a man certainly obtains enjoyment of pleasures and liberation.**

In the last part, (in bold), only 5 names are listed--Vasudeva, Padmanabha, Upendra, Hari, and Krishna. Which is the 6th one?
The sanskrit shlokas for this are missing in the same website. Either from same Purana, another source, or another Purana, please help with the missing name.

Among the 24 names, only Narayana seems to be missing here.

[image]